# How to use custom mailgun variable inside email template?

Tags: mailgun

I'm using [mailgun-js](https://github.com/bojand/mailgun-js) library to send emails from nodejs server.

How I can populate html email teamplate, which sends through mailgun, with some custom variable?

For recipient-variables it works like `%recipient.custom-variable%` in html template and with such code on server side:

```
let email = {
  from: 'my@email.com',
  to: emailsArray,
  subject: 'my subject',
  html: template,
  'recipient-variables': emailsArray.map(e=>{e:{custom-variable: user.customThing}})
};

return mailgun.create(email);
```

but I have some variable which should be the same for all recipients.

How I can set the custom variable and how I can use it inside template (in manner of recipient-variable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it's not possible to use custom variables, only with `recipient-variables`.